# Acces of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, undefined

Um im programming a little program right now, but I noticed that something wont work. When I try running my game it gives me this:
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 3, Line 16  1120: Access of undefined property NumberofWins.
I tried to look for any possible reason why this code wont work, and haven't found a reason:

```
var Numberofwins = 0;
CN.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);

function checkFrame(event:Event):void{
if(CN.currentFrame == 11){
    CN.gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
}
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, CheckIf8);

function CheckIf8(event:Event):void{
if(CN.currentFrame == 8) {
    NumberofWins++;
}
else{
    gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `var Numberofwins = 0;` should be `var NumberofWins = 0;`

or

`NumberofWins++;`should be `Numberofwins++;`

If you want to use the convention when naming vars, use camel case: `numberOfWins`. First letter lowercase except for class and constructor function names.